# Programming Ballistics. Wondering about this dy computation

Tags: javascript, physics

Hi guys so I'm learning HTML5 and JS and making some games and stuff. I'm reading the book Essential Guide to HTML5 and in it describes a ballistic type of program where in the displacement y would be:

```
verticalVel2 = verticalVel1 + gravity;
dy = (verticalVal2 + verticalVel1) * .5;
```

What I don't get is why they took the average of the velocity. 
Why not just set velocity to velocity minus gravity, then apply it to current position?

Answer (score 1):

Probably to imitate slowdown caused by the air thickness.

this example is rather for Nick, who wonders why t is absent in the equation.

```
var x = 0, y = 0, dx = 5, dy = 5
for (var t = 0; t < 150; t++) {
    x += dx, y += dy
    if (y < 0) break
    dx -= 0.1
    dy -= 0.5
    setPixel(x, y)
}
```

or this is a timer based variant

```
var x = 0, y = 0, dx = 5, dy = 5
var T = setInterval(function() {
    x += dx, y += dy
    if (y < 0) clearInterval(T)
    dx -= 0.1
    dy -= 0.5
    setPixel(x, y)
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

The y displacement of a bullet or anything like that is `y=Vi*t+1/2*a*t^2`. Typically you define upwards motion to be positive and downwards motion to be negative. `a` is the acceleration which in a standard free fall situation such as shooting something horizontally you would want to use gravity as your acceleration with the value of g being `9.8 m/s^2` or `32 ft/s^2`. It's important to remember that generally depending on your coordinate system gravity is a negative acceleration.

All of this is assuming a constant force is acting upon the object and therefore the acceleration is constant. As to why they chose to average the two things I can't really say. I'm confused as to how the velocity gives you the displacement without incorporating time. Furthermore, did you mean verticalV **e** l1 or verticalV **a** l1. If you meant verticalVal then I'm not sure what that's supposed to tell us. If you meant verticalVel as in vertical velocity, then go off of the equation given earlier. If you have any more physics related questions I can try to elaborate or answer any of them for you.

Comment: Time is absent in the equation because this is in-a-loop calculation and time is assumed to be T=1.

Comment: If it's t=1 every time then how is anything changing?

Comment: Nick, incrementally. each step you do x += dx, where dx is current velocity and calculated somewere else.

Comment: Nick check my answer above, I added very simple example to show how t is eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute the expression for `verticalVel2` in the second expression, you end up with:

```
dy = verticalVel1 + gravity * .5;
```

This makes sense if somewhere later in the code there is `y += dy;` and the [Velocity Verlet integration scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet) (or a similar one) with a unit time step (i.e. delta_t = 1) is used to solve the equation of motion.